# replace part of a background-image url with vanilla js for a series of images

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code that works well for changing a part of an src url of normal images

```
let svgz = document.querySelectorAll(".svg");
for (let i = 0; i < svgz.length; i++) {
  svgz[i].src = svgz[i].src.replace("light", "dark");
}
```

I'd like to do the same with css background-image urls.

I have created this snippet based on the above mentioned one but its not working:

```
let svgbg = document.querySelectorAll(".svgbg");
for (let i = 0; i < svgbg.length; i++) {
    svgbg[i].style.backgroundImage = svgbg[i].style.backgroundImage.replace("light", "dark");
}
```

How can I change a background images url partially?

Comment: When you say 'not working' can you tell us what errors, if any, you see in your browser's devtools console?

Comment: console is not responding to running this script

the top snippet works as meaning it changes the url of the images with class "svg" from light to dark
the bottom snippet is not working meaning its not changing the url of the background images with class "svgbg" , when the script runs the original image disappears instead of changing it to its dark equivalent

Comment: by connecting the background-image url to a variable it works, but thats pure css with a sudden switch between the two images instead fading in and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it works, it was interfering with setting the default background-image url with a variable when the page loads. If the background images is a single image independent of theme it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case where the JS toggle method comes in useful, depending on exactly what is wanted of course. Code put up here in case of use to someone wanting to toggle between two background images (actually, between any two classes):

```
<style>
.svgbg {
  background-image: url(light.svg);/* replace with your light background url */
}
.svgbgdark {
  background-image:url(dark.svg);/* replace with your dark background url */
}
</style>
<div class="svgbg"></div>
<script>
let svgbg = document.querySelectorAll(".svgbg");
for (let i = 0; i < svgbg.length; i++) {
  svgbg.classList.toggle('svgbgdark');
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is also a good idea, but as I was experimenting more with the code I pasted in the question it turned out there was no problem with it at all, it was just interfering with setting the url first with a variable for the two themes. if its a single images it changes it without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check the snippet below and let me know if this solves the problem.

```js
let svgbg = document.querySelectorAll(".svgbg");
let bg = " url('img_tree.png')"

console.log(bg);

for (let i = 0; i < svgbg.length; i++) {
//set your updated bg path here
    bg = " url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/08/19/00/13/sea-5499649__340.jpg')"
    console.log(bg);
    svgbg[i].style.backgroundImage = bg
}
```

```css
.svgbg {

  background-size: 100% auto;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgbg"></div>
```